# Question about this white regulatory sign

Tags: word-meaning

> **Two way traffic ahead**

I am wondering if you could help me defining the sign in simple English.

Is the word **traffic** noun or adjective?

This is a regulatory sign not a written thing on a board.

Comment: You're positive it's not two way?

Comment: "Tow way" doesn't make grammatical sense, unless there is a street called "Tow Way" and it is a high source of traffic. It seems more likely that it reads ["two way"](http://www.safetysign.com/images/catlog/product/large/X4530.png).

Comment: I corrected my mistake. It is two way

Comment: There is mis spelling for sign in last sentence

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations/law. Incorrect or misapplied Answers to such questions could cause legal or physical harm. (As read by anyone, at any time in the future, who may live anywhere.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Two-way traffic ahead* means that there are vehicles ahead of you which are moving in two opposing directions.

You'd generally see this sign on a one-way road (on which vehicles move in only one direction) before transitioning to a road which has vehicles moving in opposing directions.

Here, *traffic* is a noun, referring to the moving vehicles. *Two-way* is treated as an adjective, qualifying the term *traffic*.

Comment: @user5036 You should accept it if it is what you were looking for